# Is this fake kindness?

Tags: behavior

If I do kindness because I want God to give me rewards / presents , what kind of kindness is this ? . Is this kindness fake / not genuine ? Insincere kindness ?. Does God love humans who do fake / insincere kindness ?

Comment: In islam the ideal is: we do kindness because we want to please God

Answer (score 1):

No. Every action has an intention or motive or incentive behind it (and those who say otherwise are mistaken). So a person's intentions can either be for worldly reasons [in which case it is insincere/vain] or it can be for Allah's (ﷻ) sake (His Pleasure, His Reward, etc).

Doing kindness with the intention of seeking Allah's (ﷻ) reward is perfectly fine. There are many ahadith in which we are told that we will be rewarded if we do acts of good with the intention of seeking Allah's (ﷻ) reward (e.g., [prayer/fast](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/209), [spending on family](https://sunnah.com/muslim/12/59), etc). Had this been blameworthy, we would then not be subsequently rewarded and would rather be rebuked. But that is not the case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Doing things to please your creator is never viewed as a bad thing. If you feel like your only being kind to please Allah that doesn't take away from the fact that you acted kindly. This is good.

- **Pure niyyah** or intention is often defined with acts that are done to
  please Allah.
- **Insincere niyyah** would be intention to gain in this world. This are things which are done in vain meaning for the sake of your pride or ego.

An example, a person who offers prayers in front of others just to be seen as pious. Or by himself he speeds through the salah, but in congregation reads the longest surah and takes his time to impress others. This is insincere, his rewards for such actions will be decided by Allah. In the Qur'an it tells us to avoid such actions.

"Allah does not impose blame upon you for what is unintentional in your oaths, but He imposes blame upon you for what your hearts have earned. And Allah is Forgiving and Forbearing." (2:225)